# GRASS r.viewshed from Python with multiple raster tiles

Tags: python, raster, grass-gis, merge, viewshed

I'm new to GRASS and struggling to do a viewshed across multiple tiles. I have got the GRASS r.viewshed function working from Python as follows for a single tile:

```
gis_path = os.path.join(output_dir, 'gisdb')
output_filename = '{}-viewshed.tif'.format(filename)
transmitter_coords = str(x_transmitter) + ',' + str(y_transmitter)

with Session(gisdb=gis_path, location="location", create_opts="EPSG:27700"):

    print(gcore.parse_command("g.gisenv", flags="s"))
    gcore.run_command('r.external', input=tile_path, output=filename, overwrite=True)
    gcore.run_command('r.external.out', directory=output_dir, format="GTiff")
    gcore.run_command('g.region', raster=filename)
    gcore.run_command('r.viewshed',flags='b',input=filename,output=output_filename,coordinates=transmitter_coords,overwrite=True)
    gcore.run_command('r.external.out', flags="r")
```

What is the right way to do this for multiple tiles? I have the following attempt with a loop that correctly reads in a list of file paths:

```
with Session(gisdb=gis_path, location="location", create_opts="EPSG:27700"):

    print(gcore.parse_command("g.gisenv", flags="s"))

    for tile in list_of_tiles:

        output_filename = '{}-viewshed.tif'.format(tile[-10:-4])
        gcore.message('Importing %s -> %s@%s...' % (tile, tile[-10:], output_dir))
        gcore.run_command('r.external', input=tile, output=output_filename, overwrite=True)
        gcore.run_command('r.external.out', directory=output_dir, format="GTiff")
```

I'm unsure if I now need to merge together the individual files (not sure how to do this) or to feed r.viewshed a list (which I haven't been able to do).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should patch together all tiles and then do `r.viewshed` on the patched raster.
Here is what it might look like:

```
import os
with Session(gisdb=gis_path, location="location", create_opts="EPSG:27700"):
    print(gcore.parse_command("g.gisenv", flags="s"))
    for tile in list_of_tiles:
        base, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.split(tile)[1])
        tile_name = "tile_%s" % base
        gcore.run_command('r.import', input=tile, output=tile_name, overwrite=True)

    rast_list = gcore.read_command('g.list', type='rast', pattern="tile_*", separator="comma").strip().split('\n')
    gcore.run_command('g.region', rast=rast_list, flags='p')
    gcore.run_command('r.patch', input=rast_list, output="all_tiles")
    gcore.run_command('r.viewshed',flags='b',input=all_tiles, output="viewshed", coordinates=transmitter_coords, overwrite=True)
```

Now export "viewshed" to Geotiff with `r.out.gdal` or `r.external.out` as you did above.

Comment: Dear Micha, this partially worked but do you know why my rast_list returns 
 this output: b'tile_TL45NE,tile_TL45NW' ? I am unsure of by the 'b' is included?

Comment: What version of python? The b'...' indicates a byte string. You should be able to just to `decode('UTF-8')` on the rast_list string.

Answer (score 0):

For an easy approach, you can use [r.buildvrt](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/r.buildvrt.html) in order to build a VRT (Virtual Raster) from the list of input raster maps. It works similar to `gdalbuildvrt` but straight with GRASS GIS raster maps. On the resulting virtual map just run `r.viewshed`.

Note that you need to use at least GRASS GIS 7.6 in order to have `r.buildvrt`. The official release shall be in the next weeks but it is already available as a weekly snapshot from https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/