# No output layer while using GRASS r.viewshed in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, grass-gis, viewshed

I have a DEM (in EPSG 3857; same as project EPSG) and try to create a viewshed with GRASS [`r.viewshed`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.viewshed.html). Function seems to run fine. However, when it is over there is a message that no output layer (tif-file) has been created with. Protocol says

```
{'output': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':[file path]/view.tif, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>}
```

Working with QGIS 3.12.0 on Win 10 (x64).

A possible hint: I tried also the Visibility Analysis Pluging. When I tried to create Viewpoints with this tool, I get the following erroer-message:

> Raster pixels are irregular in shape (probably due to incorrect
>   projection)!

However, my DEM is in EPSG 3857, a projected CRS - you can't use a geographic CRS for Viewshed analysis, if my information is correct.

Any idea what went wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: I checked, no special characters and I try to safe view.tif to a folder with writing persmission

Comment: Problem seems to be linked to Input-Layer (DEM) - I tried another DEM succesfully. However, I can't say what was the difference between the two DEMs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After verification of your TIFF/TIF input I would suggest reprojecting it to a different CRS, more common for Ukrainian territory [EPSG:5561](https://epsg.io/5561), a.k.a. UCS-2000 / USK-2000. And afterwards set up the project-CRS exactly to the same CRS as your TIFF/TIF-file.

As well I would double check if your path to the input/output folder have any special characters or empy spaces in it? Do you have permission of writing the view.tif? How much memory capacity do you use?

---

**References:**

- [GRASS r.viewshed from Python with multiple raster tiles](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306783/grass-r-viewshed-from-python-with-multiple-raster-tiles)
- [Coordinate Reference Systems of Ukraine](http://crs.bkg.bund.de/crseu/crs/eu-countrysel.php?country=UA)
- [Transformation Parameters between UCS-2000 and WGS-84](https://journals.vgtu.lt/index.php/GAC/article/view/1830/2823)
- [*in Ukrainian* Банк геодезичних даних Державної геодезичної мережі та геодезичних мереж згущення](https://dgm.gki.com.ua/map/shema-dgm#map=6//47.264320080254805//30.739746093750004&&layer=2012332222387848919-1,100//1957486367818647401-1,100//12052842560826521-1,100//12058222771252388-1,100//12058227116485797-0,100)

Comment: I reprojected the DEM to EPSG 5561 - it works with this reprojected layer, but only when I set the project-EPSG to the same CRS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in the Visibility Analysis Plugin. I had failed to project my tiff properly to the desired CRS, I had simply exported the file and saved it under the CRS I wanted(wrong thing to do). In Qgis 3: Raster>Projections>Warp(reproject).